# How to clear selection in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How to clear the current selection (unselect selected objects) programmatically in fabric.js?

After a user hast selected a group, my custom event handler for "selected" runs. Now the group is selected. But I would like it not to be selected.

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462307/fabric-js-how-to-deselect-one-or-multiple-objects-on-canvas

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch()` or just `canvas.deactivateAll()` if no events should be triggered. Then `canvas.renderAll()` might be required.